# If $v\times w = 4i + 7j + 5k$ then what is $v\times w + w\times v$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, 3d

> If $v\times w = 4i + 7j + 5k$ then what is $v\times w + w\times v$?

$v$ and $w$ are vectors, they aren't given. I have no idea how to do this and apparently it's asked on a quiz as a "surprise" question.

Comment: The edited title and question were significantly more readable. When rendered, the command \times is displayed as the appropriate cross product symbol. The title is now not very unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the cross product is what we call anti-commutative, i.e.

$$(\vec{v} \times \vec{w}) = - (\vec{w} \times \vec{v})$$

I feel like this fact will simplify your work greatly.

Comment: thanks! I figured it out if I'm correct, the answer would be 0?

Comment: Well, the zero vector, $\vec{0} = 0\hat{i} + 0\hat{j} + 0\hat{k}$, more appropriately, but yeah you get the idea.